# Border-bottom showing when it should not

Tags: html, css, border

I have a small div block as shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzmyLo3r/4/). This div contains another div (lines 9 to 17 in the fiddle) that is shown whenever there is a problem (execution led by javascript, not relevant here):

```
                <div class="ui-state-default ui-widget-header plupload_header">
                  <div class="plupload_header_content">
                    <div class="plupload_logo"> </div>
                    <div class="plupload_header_title">Sélectionnez les fichiers (max. 80 Mo)</div>
                    <div class="plupload_header_text">Ajoutez des fichiers à la file d'attente de téléchargement et appuyez sur le bouton 'Démarrer l'envoi'</div>
                    <div class="plupload_view_switch" style="display: none;"><input type="radio" id="plupload_container_view_thumbs" name="view_mode_plupload_container" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label class="plupload_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" for="plupload_container_view_thumbs"
                        data-view="thumbs" role="button" title="Miniatures"><span class="ui-button-text">Miniatures</span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-image"></span></label></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

In the corresponding css, there is a small snippet (shown next) that, apart from other css snippets, is giving support for it.

```
.ui-state-default.ui-widget-header.plupload_header {
  z-index: 99999999;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 59px;
  width: 98.7%;
  background: transparent !important;
  border-bottom-style: hidden;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I can't get rid of the bottom gray border (see image below for clarity) despite it is hidden (according to CSS). Even if it is not very visible, by checking it closer to the screen you will see the gray border. How can I remove it? Thank you for your help.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qzmyLo3r/4/)

[image]

**UPDATE**

The div part will show error messages (made by JS) when there is a problem with the upload. Something like this:

[image]

You can see above that the gray line is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `border: none;`

```
.ui-state-default.ui-widget-header.plupload_header {
  z-index: 99999999;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 59px;
  width: 98.7%;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the only valid answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's happening for `ui-state-default ui-widget-header plupload_header` element. To remove it, use this CSS:

```
.ui-state-default.ui-widget-header.plupload_header {
  display: none;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fogj98de/**

Comment: This is not valid because I have to display it. Actually, this div will show error messages when there is a problem in the upload (to be generated via JS). I just updated the main question to show you what I am talking about.

Comment: @juanba1984 I forgot to write `border: none` and wrote `display: none`. Alright. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `!important` in your CSS code here:

```
div#plupload_container_dropbox {
    border: 2px solid #ff0051 !important;
    border-style: dashed !important;
    border-radius: 14px !important;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

So, you have to override the border bottom with `!important` as well. Moreover, your overriding must come after the code above.

```
div#plupload_container_dropbox {
    /* Add this */
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

PS. Don't use `!important` unless you really-really have to.

Comment: No, this is totally a different border OP is talking about.

Comment: Yeap, looks like it.